# Check the VCS environment variables Veritas

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, high-availability

I'm trying to check the VCS (Veritas Cluster Server) environment variables on a Linux system. Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried using the 'haenv' command, but I'm not getting the output I expect. Are there any other methods I can use to check the VCS environment variables? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
https://sort.veritas.com/public/documents/sf/5.0/solaris64/html/vcs_users/ch_vcsconfiguration_concepts15.html#219218